# replaceFirst for character "`"

Tags: java, replace, escaping

First time here. I'm trying to write a program that takes a string input from the user and encode it using the replaceFirst method. All letters and symbols with the exception of "`" (Grave accent) encode and decode properly.

e.g. When I input

```
`12
```

I am supposed to get 28AABB as my encryption, but instead, it gives me BB8AA2

```
public class CryptoString {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {

    String input = "";

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the string to be encrypted");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The message " + input + " was encrypted to be "+ encrypt(input));



public static String encrypt (String s){
    String encryptThis = s.toLowerCase();
    String encryptThistemp = encryptThis;
    int encryptThislength = encryptThis.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < encryptThislength ; ++i){
        String test = encryptThistemp.substring(i, i + 1);
        //Took out all code with regard to all cases OTHER than "`" "1" and "2"
        //All other cases would have followed the same format, except with a different string replacement argument.
        if (test.equals("`")){
            encryptThis = encryptThis.replaceFirst("`" , "28");
        }
        else if (test.equals("1")){
            encryptThis = encryptThis.replaceFirst("1" , "AA");
        }
        else if (test.equals("2")){
            encryptThis = encryptThis.replaceFirst("2" , "BB");
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried putting escape characters in front of the grave accent, however, it is still not encoding it properly.

Comment: Do you really have an `else` without an `if`?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Posting real code that you are using will be more helpful.

Comment: I removed all the other cases, only showing this specific case.

Comment: Additionally, `encryptThis.replaceFirst("\`", "28")` correctly replaces `\`` with `"28"`.

Comment: It's unclear how your encryption is supposed to handle the other characters, your `else if` has no preceding `if`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at how your program works in each loop iteration:

1. - `i=0`
   - `encryptThis = '12` (I used ' instead of ` to easier write this post)
   - and now you replace ' with 28 so it will become 2812
2. - `i=1`
   - we read character at position 1 and it is `1` so
   - we replace 1 with AA making `2812` -> `28AA2`
3. - `i=2`
   - we read character at position 2, it is `2` so
   - we replace **first** `2` with `BB` making `2812` -> `BB8AA2`

---

Try maybe using `appendReplacement` from `Matcher` class from `java.util.regex` package like

```
public static String encrypt(String s) {
    Map<String, String> replacementMap = new HashMap<>();
    replacementMap.put("`", "28");
    replacementMap.put("1", "AA");
    replacementMap.put("2", "BB");

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[`12]"); //regex that will match ` or 1 or 2
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while (m.find()){//we found one of `, 1, 2
        m.appendReplacement(sb, replacementMap.get(m.group()));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`encryptThistemp.substring(i, i + 1);` The second parameter of substring is length, are you sure you want to be increasing `i`? because this would mean after the first iteration `test` would not be 1 character long. This could throw off your other cases **which we cannot see!**